# Difficulties finding $|z-3|>|z-1+4i|$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I am ask to draw the numbers $z$ that satisfy $|z-3|>|z-1+4i|$.

I have:
$$|z-3|>|z-1+4i| \iff (x-3)^2+y^2>(x-1)^2+(y+4)^2$$
$$ \iff x^2-6x+9>x^2-2x+1+y^2+8y+16$$
$$\iff x<-2y-2$$

This, however, is not the correct answer. Can anyone help me finding the correct answer?

Comment: What is the supposed correct answer?

Comment: It was a region drawed on a sheet of paper, there is no 'explicit' answer included in the file. All I can see is that the line I drawed, according to this calculations, does not match the line on the answer file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the correct answer. The region is the set of all points in the plane that are closer to $3$ than they are to $1-4i$. That would be the open half-plane below (or, to the left of) the line $y=-\frac12 x -1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Use the isomorphism from $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ as vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ and note that $|z-3|$ is the distance of a point $(x,y)$ from $A=(3,0)$ and $|z-1+4i|$ is the distance from $B=(1,-4)$. Can you find the axis of the segment $AB$?

This is a geometrical vision of your answer!